# three.js raycaster.intersectObject() returning same faceIndex every time

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I have a 3D cube rendered with THREE.CanvasRenderer(), and i'm trying to open a specific webpage depending on which face of the cube is double clicked. However, the same page is opened no matter what face is clicked. Some hacked debugging (i don't know how to use the console) reveals that intersects[ 0 ].faceIndex is always '11'. How can i get it to return the nearest face of the cube.

Here is the section of my js that handles this;

```js
document.addEventListener('dblclick', onDocumentMouseDblClick, false);

function onDocumentMouseDblClick(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    mouse.x = (event.clientX / renderer.domElement.width) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = -(event.clientY / renderer.domElement.height) * 2 + 1;

    raycaster.setFromCamera(mouse, camera);

    var intersects = raycaster.intersectObject(cube);

    if (intersects.length > 0) {
      if (intersects[0].faceIndex = 1 || 2) {
        window.open("About.html", "_self")
          //title.innerHTML = intersects[ 0 ].faceIndex;
      }
      if (intersects[0].faceIndex = 3 || 4) {
        window.open("Mondrian.html", "_self")
          //title.innerHTML = intersects[ 0 ].faceIndex;
      }
      if (intersects[0].faceIndex = 5 || 6) {
        window.open("page3.html", "_self")
          //title.innerHTML = intersects[ 0 ].faceIndex;
      }
      if (intersects[0].faceIndex = 7 || 8) {
        window.open("page4.html", "_self")
          //title.innerHTML = intersects[ 0 ].faceIndex;
      }
      if (intersects[0].faceIndex = 9 || 10) {
        window.open("page5.html", "_self")
          //title.innerHTML = intersects[ 0 ].faceIndex;
      }
      if (intersects[0].faceIndex = 11 || 12) {
        window.open("page6.html", "_self")
          //title.innerHTML = intersects[ 0 ].faceIndex;
      }
```

I started by following the [THREE.js interactive cubes example](http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_interactive_cubes) and reading the [THREE.raycaster documentation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/Raycaster) reveals that the intersections should be ordered by closest distance. I've read through some SO posts that use Vector3's and unprojections, which either don't work or i misunderstand them. Can't link them because reputation.

Comment: You can always put links in your question, with or without reputation...

Comment: not more than two links, without rep more than zero

Comment: you are not checking for equality, you are making assignments in your if statements.

Comment: well that's super embarrassing :/. I actually make that mistake often, i'm going to be extra vigilant for it from now on. Solved it though, so thank you!

Comment: @dlseanan Well I learned something today :)

Comment: converted my comment to an answer

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it should be:

```
if (intersects[0].faceIndex === 1 || intersects[0].faceIndex === 2) {
```